# можно ли получить видео поток окна в windows

Tags: c++, python, c, windows, winapi

У нас есть какая-то запущенная оконная программа. Мне нужно получать кадры изображения этого окна, как только они обновляются. Как такое сделать под Windows.

Comment: Теоретически... нужно перехватить пути получения дескриптора контекста окна (HDC) подсунув туда "свой" дескриптор, который будет "проброшен" - но это - написание драйвера - зачача не из простых. Более простой способ (но менее хороший) - подсунуть hdc битмапа, и анализировать были ли изменения в нем с определенной частотой + проброс на экран.

Comment: Повесить на целевое окно хук WH_CALLWNDPROCRET и отлавливать сообщение WM_PAINT, после чего копировать его изображение с помощью BitBlt/StretchBlt и т. п.